Oracle : how to rename table to create editioning view?
I'm trying to use EBR feature in Oracle.
According to the documentation here, in order to make a live change in a production table, I have to create an editioning view that has the same name as my table. This view will "replace" the real table in the packages until the corresponding changes are made in packages.
But before that I need to rename the table to something else:
For example:
ALTER TABLE Contacts RENAME TO Contacts_Table;

I don't understand how this may work because when running this code in a certain edition, the table is renamed in all the other editions, hence invalidating the packages in the live production edition.
How can I rename a table in a specific edition only?

Tables are not editionable objects so you can't have a table with different names in different editions.
When you rename the table, it will be renamed in all editions.  If you then create an editioning view with the name of the table (in your case, a view named Contacts) then all your code will reference that editioned view.  If you already have multiple editions, you'd need to ensure that the editioning view exists in each edition that you want to be usable.
Once your code has dependencies on the editioned view rather than the non-editionable table, then you can evolve the view definition and/or the package definition in one edition without impacting the code and/or view definition in the live edition.

Thank you for your answer. Yes I got the fact that tables are not editionable. But I don't get how can we get no downtime, If we need first to stop the database to rename the tables so that we can edit the views. Let's ask it differently, using EBR, how can I make a change to a table without a downtime ?
